# Finding the argmaximum of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've been doing project euler problems in Haskell, and often I've found the need to get the value that gives the maximum of a function.

For example,

```
answer = argmaximum $ map collatzLength [1..10^6]
```

Where collatzLength is a previously defined function.

I came up with this code, which is heavily influenced by learning Ocaml. I run a helper function that has variables that keep track of the best value index and best index so far.
It works perfectly for positive lists, but it seems like there's a better way.

Is there a less clunky way to implement argmaximum?

```
argmaximum :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> a
argmaximum lst = helper lst 0 0 0 where
  helper (x:xs) current bestVal bestIndex
    | current > bestVal = helper xs (current + 1) x current
    | otherwise = helper xs (current + 1) bestVal bestIndex
  helper null _ _ bestIndex = bestIndex
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for `maxmimumBy (comparing collatzLength) [1..10^6]` or `maximumBy (compare \`on\` collatzLength) [1..10^6]`. I’m not sure I understand how your function works, unless `current > bestVal` is a typo and meant to be `x > bestVal`. It’s late so I’m afraid I cannot review more thoroughly - I do hope at least one of my suggestions type checks.

Answer (score 1):

What you have implemented here is strictly speaking not argmaximum, but finding a maximum index in a list. The difference is that your argmaximum will not return the correct value for invocations that don't `map` from `[1..?]`

Instead of that, you probably wanted something that's typed as follows:

```
argmax :: (Ord a, Num a) => (b -> a) -> [b] -> b
argmax f (d:ds) = ...
```

That way you can write `argmax collatzLength [500..10^6]` and still get the correct answer :)

By the way: [@cole](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/183567/cole) suggested using `maximumBy` and `comparing` for the implementation, which I wholeheartedly agree on :)